# Are there any short single words that differentiate between ratio and sum type relativity?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been digging through the thesaurus and I can't seem to find a good word.  The impetus for this is that I'm a programmer and I'd like a short, sweet way to distinguish between two very similar but also very different things.

I have a list of things, like pages in a book, and sometimes I want to get a page by number, and other times by relative position (like the page half way through the book).

Naming a function for getting a page by number is easy `getPage(pageNum: number)`.  But I can never figure out what to call the other one... `getPageFromRatioOfLength(ratioOfLength: number)` is a bit too verbose.

So my question is, if someone had $10.00 and got taxed $5.00, what kind of words could they use to ask whether they had been taxed -$5.00 or -50%?  Are there any short, sweet, single terms that can describe and differentiate between these two forms of movement and relativity?

Comment: I've found a very interesting semi-applicable term which is angle.  It doesn't feel totally right, but it does imply a sort of circular, slice image, rather than a measuring tape kind.

Comment: `getPageFromPercent`? or `getPageRelative` vs `getPageAbsolute`?

Comment: When a variable has a range from 0 to 1, it is called normalized. So `getPageNorm` would be a possibility. However, in your case it looks awfully similar to `getPageNum`, so I would use `getPageRaw` and `getPageNorm`. Since it is a common convention to use a caret (circumflex) to mark normalized variables, `getPageNumCaret` would also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Absolute vs relative*](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-absolute-and-relative/)

Where absolute implies the change has the same units as your original amount (i.e. -5 is in dollars because the 10 was in dollars) whereas relative would be a unitless amount (considering that original 10 dollar amount as a single unit)

Another way to say it might be *units vs percentage*

Comment: hmmm... even though it's the opposite of how you're using the word, I like units a lot for ratio stuff.

Something like `getUnitOfPages(pagesUnit)` seems really usable and makes sense to me.

getUnitOfFrames, getUnitOfTriathalon, getUnitOfSpan.

I still feel like the "UnitOf" might have a better substitute, but this is definitely getting somewhere.

Comment: I think `Unit` strongly implies absolute numbers rather than percentages and using it to mean a percentage change would be very confusing.

Comment: It's funny, I hear it the opposite way.  Like, if I said I had 0.5 units of water, one would ask what the unit was, but no matter what it would be half that unit.  So a way to say, the "unit of this number is the total number of pages" seems very applicable to me.

Comment: @SephReed if you have units of pages, no one is going to ask what the unit is, because it is pages i.e. single pages. Thus 0.5 units of pages means half a page and *not* half of all the pages. The same goes for dollars...

Comment: Perhaps unit of book then

Comment: Pages and dollars are both already units.

Comment: `getPageFromNumber()` vs `getPageFromPercent()`?

Comment: getPageFromPercent is definitely closer, but percent implies going from 0-100.  In my case, the number goes from 0-1, which is the normal span of a unit.  So maybe getPageFromUnit, which is pretty close to getPageFromRatio (the thing I've bee using).  Could also do getUnitPage.

In any case, I really liked your answer.  I just happen to think of the word unit differently.

Comment: getPageUnited!  It's the getPage function in a united form.  This'll work for for me quite well.

Comment: defining percentage between 0 and 1 is very common, especially amongst programmers.

Comment: united means together - that will also be confusing

Comment: In the particular program I'm using, there are user inputs which go from 0-100 and translate to 0-1.  Because of this, use of the word percentage is touchy.  And it's unit ed, not united.  As in, made into a unit.  I unit-ed by arm length, that car is 20 arms long.

Comment: I get you're trying to say unit-ed but anyone reading it is going to read united as you-knighted, that's all I'm saying

Comment: That's very true, and for something like a function call, I may never use the term.  But I think it'll still come in handy for variable names.  Thanks again!